# How to set difference pointer over color for each row in ListView UWP

Tags: listview, uwp

I trying to make a ListView which have some row will have difference PointerOver color with others (depend on data binding on this rows). Currently, I tried to change ListViewItemBackgroundSelected when Pointer move to any row

```js
private void lvResult_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            lvResult.SelectedItem = ((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext;
            Debug.WriteLine("Hover Item :" + lvResult.SelectedIndex);
            if (lvResult.SelectedIndex % 2 == 0){ //just put sample condition here
            lvResult.Resources["ListViewItemBackgroundPointerOver"] = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(150, 250, 12, 170));
            lvResult.Resources["ListViewItemBackgroundSelected"] = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(150, 250, 12, 170)); 
       lvResult.Resources["ListViewItemBackgroundSelectedPointerOver"] = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(150, 250, 12, 170));
            }else{
            lvResult.Resources["ListViewItemBackgroundPointerOver"] = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(150, 255, 0, 255));
            lvResult.Resources["ListViewItemBackgroundSelected"] = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(150, 255, 0, 255));   
     lvResult.Resources["ListViewItemBackgroundSelectedPointerOver"] = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(150, 255, 0, 255));
            }
           
        }
```

But look like it not working. So could you please give me a help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, the `lvResult.SelectedItem` is not the item where pointer over.

You could add the `PointerEntered` event in a `Grid` within a `DataTemplate` of `ListView.ItemTemplate` to set the Grid’s background. You need to replace your data binding in the following code.

Please check the following code as a sample:

```
public sealed class MyClass
{
    public bool flag { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public MyClass()
    {
        flag = false;
        Name = "name";
    }
}



//MainPage.xaml
<ListView x:Name="lvResult" ItemsSource="{x:Bind collections}"> //Replace your data binding here
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="dt" x:DataType="local:MyClass">
            <Grid x:Name="itemGrid" Height="40" Width="1000"
                        PointerExited="itemGrid_PointerExited"
                        PointerEntered="itemGrid_PointerEntered">
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" ></TextBlock>  //Replace your data binding here
                <TextBlock x:Name="tb" Visibility="Collapsed" Text="{x:Bind flag}"/>  //Replace your data binding here
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>

//MainPage.xaml.cs
private ObservableCollection<MyClass> collections;

private void itemGrid_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var grid = sender as Grid;
    var myClass = grid.DataContext as MyClass;

    if (myClass!=null)
    {
        if (myClass.flag==true)
        {
            grid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        }
    }
}



private void itemGrid_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var grid = sender as Grid;
    grid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
}
```

Comment: I found the solution before your answer but more or less it same with your idea. Anyway, thank you for all !

Answer (score 0):

Even it could potentially work, I am not sure it's a good idea.

If you are trying to highlight some row items with a different color based on some conditions, it's better to have a data template to achieve it.

For example, in your listview, you may have something like this:

```
<ListView
    SelectionMode="Single"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListViewTemplate}"/>
```

in your data template, you can use different options to apply different hovering colors, e.g. Trigger, Converter (binding to a model property) or Template Selector